# In my C# project,I want to exit Method1 on a specific condition, and execute Method2 without coming back to Method1 again. How can I do that?

Tags: c#, if-statement, return, goto

In my C# project, I want to exit Method1 on a specific condition and execute another method (Method2) without return back to Method1. I want to prevent using jump statements (goto). How can I do that?

My simplified code looks like

```
 public void Method1 ()
 {
   if (condition==true)
    {
      Method2() // Here at this point I want to exit Method1 and execute Method2. That means after executing Method2 the program shall not return to Method1. How can I do that?
    }
   //some code
 }
```

Comment: Under `Method2()` do `return;` that will exit Method1() after Method2() executes.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. For example, why can't you just call the second method after the call to the first returns? Please try to clarify.

Comment: To an `if` there is an `else` ...

Comment: after `if` put `else` or after call `Method2()` put `return;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can return after the method call.

```
if (condition == true)
{
    Method2();
    return;
}
```

Alternatively, you can put `else` for this `if` statement so that it will run only `Method2()` if it goes inside the `if`.

```
if (condition == true)
{
    Method2();
}
else
{
    //Do something
}
```

Another way is to have to same return type (except void) (if applicable) for both methods and return like below.

```
if (condition == true)
{
    return Method2();
}
```